# Problems in ctor of Jint in .NET 4.5

Tags: constructor, .net-4.5, jint

I'm using Jint, the 4.5 .NET version, of Sebastien Ros.
And javascript prototype objects, and I want to call the javascript prototype constructor with an object.

I run into some problems here.
Someting like this:

```
function Panel(objectBehind)
{
  log(objectBehind);
}
Panel.prototype.objectBehind;
```

1) How do I create a new Panel object, calling the ctor parameters?
I got this far:

```
 engine.Execute(script);
 engine.Execute("new Panel();");
 JsValue val = engine.GetCompletionValue();
```

But then the ctor argument is empty, of course.

2) Suppose I want to set the  objectBehind property on the  newed java prototype object, how would that work on the JsValue object?

3) I probably could use a named var, and then call the poperty, but then I need to add named vars:

```
       engine.Execute(script);
       engine.Execute("var myPanel = new Panel();");
       //do the set prop on mypanel from here.
```

Comment: I think I cracked it:




    engine.Execute(@"function Panel(objectBehind)
    {
       this.objectBehind = objectBehind;
       return this;//bit strange and unusual pattern
    }
    Panel.prototype.objectBehind;");

    JsValue resultCTor = engine.Invoke("Panel", 1);
    JsValue objectBehind = engine.GetValue(resultCTor, "objectBehind");

Answer (score 2):

I think I cracked it:

```
engine.Execute(@"function Panel(objectBehind)
{
   this.objectBehind = objectBehind;
   return this;//bit strange and unusual pattern
}
Panel.prototype.objectBehind;");

JsValue resultCTor = engine.Invoke("Panel", 1);
JsValue objectBehind = engine.GetValue(resultCTor, "objectBehind");
```